# Problem in recovering with Linux, testdisk

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I was installing Linux, but suddenly I found that when I start my PC it shows this texts: `Grub-welcome` or something like that. I try to recover my PC with Linux in live and started using test-disk. I ran it, used analyses, deep search, and I found my partitions. Copied them into /home then copied the file into my external hard, but every file shows just 0B. All of the files are in front of me with their names, but none of them can be opened.

What should I do ?